# Moving Snakemake's conda environments to another location

Tags: conda, snakemake

I would like to know if it's possible to move the ./snakemake/conda to a new location without Snakemake trying to reinstall all environments with a new hash (yaml). For example moving /mnt/Serge/.snakemake/conda to /mnt/tools/.snakemake/conda. I've already tried to copy the folder to the new location and adjust `--conda-prefix /mnt/Serge/.snakemake/conda` to `--conda-prefix /mnt/tools/.snakemake/conda` but that didn't work out and it started to create new environments next to the old ones. Does this have to do with symlinks and how do I solve this issue without reinstalling all the tools?